# Getting Auto Number for Just Inserted Record

Tags: apex

Is there no other way other than using a SOQL request to get get the object I just inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ways we have to get that information are:

- To query the record after inserting it
- If you have a formula field that copies an auto number field, you could call `Formula.recalculateFormulas()` ([relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Formula.htm)), but that would consume a SOQL query behind the scenes
- If you're in a trigger context, that information is available in trigger context variables in `after insert`, `before update`, `after update`, and `after undelete`) (and also probably in delete contexts, though it's probably not going to be too useful there). Notably, this information is *not* available `before insert`.

The only information I've seen be made automatically available, without querying, after a record is inserted is the Id, and RecordTypeId (if you have multiple record types available on the SObject).

A query is going to be the easiest and most straightforward way to get at that additional information. If you absolutely cannot use another query, you could make do by having your trigger (or trigger handler if you're using a trigger framework) add that information (or just the entire triggered record) to a static `Map<Id, MyObject__c>` defined in an Apex class.

It would need to be a static map defined in an *Apex class*, and not the trigger, because static variables defined in a trigger are cleared out between contexts and between chunks (so statics defined in triggers are effectively useless).

Given that you do get automatic access to the new record Id, you could use that to find the other information from the trigger context after your DML insert concludes.

Comment: the issue is this is for a sync response for a rest resource there are loads of formulas on that page so recalling isn't advisable I guess a second SOQL is required however wasteful it seems